# LINQ query, use Union or Intersect?

Tags: sql-server, linq-to-entities

I am working on a asp mvc app.
I am putting together a query that 2 lists of names from 2 different tables, then should put them together.  The query is in a method so I can call it easily.  The problem I am running into is I get an error, regardless of whether I try Union or Intersect.  The error is:

"Model.PersonAttributes does not contain a definition for Union (or Intersect) and the best overload, blah blah..."

Here is my code:

```
    public List<SearchAndMergeViewModel> SearchForMerge(string FName, string LName, string DOB)
    {
        var query = from p in _Elig_DB.PersonAttributes.ToList()
                            where p.getDateOfBirth == DOB &&
                             (p.FirstName.Contains(FName) || p.FirstName.StartsWith(FName) &&
                             p.LastName.Contains(LName) || p.LastName.StartsWith(LName))
                            select p;



        var queryb = from a in _Elig_DB.PersonAlias.ToList()
                     join e in _Elig_DB.PersonAttributes.ToList() on a.PersonID equals e.PersonID
                     where a.FirstName == FName && a.LastName == LName
                     select new SearchAndMergeViewModel
                     {
                         FirstN = a.FirstName,
                         LastN = a.LastName,
                         DOB = e.DOB
                     };

        var results = query.Intersect(queryb);

        return results.ToList();
    }
```

The above error is connected to the line "var results = query.Intersect(queryb);".

I also get an error, "Type arguments for method Enumerable.ToList can not be inferred from the usage."

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
    public List<SearchAndMergeViewModel> SearchForMerge
       (string firstName, string lastName, string dateOfBirth)
    {
        var queryA =
            from a in _Elig_DB.PersonAttributes.ToList()
            where
                a.getDateOfBirth == dateOfBirth 
                && a.FirstName.Contains(firstName)
                && a.LastName.Contains(lastName)
            select new SearchAndMergeViewModel
            {
                FirstN = a.FirstName,
                LastN = a.LastName,
                DOB = a.getDateOfBirth
            };

        var queryB = 
            from b in _Elig_DB.PersonAlias
            join a in _Elig_DB.PersonAttributes
                on new { b.PersonID, b.FirstName, b.LastName }
                equals new { a.PersonID, a.FirstName, a.LastName }
            select new SearchAndMergeViewModel
            {
                FirstN = a.FirstName,
                LastN = a.LastName,
                DOB = a.getDateOfBirth
            };

        var results = queryA.Intersect(queryB);

        return results.ToList();
    }
```

I gave your code a little revamp while I was at it but the important thing is that I am casting the **first** result to SearchAndMergeViewModel as well.

Also, removed the redundant StartsWith(...) filters.

I assume PersonAttributes.getDateOfBirth is a calculated property. If not, you should remove ToList() from the first query as well. You don't want to load your entire table into EF if you don't have to.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I needed to specify the returned columns in the first query, so they both match:

```
    public List<SearchAndMergeViewModel> SearchForMerge(string FName, string LName, string DOB)
    {
        var query = from p in _Elig_DB.PersonAttributes.ToList()
                    where p.getDateOfBirth == DOB &&
                     (p.FirstName.Contains(FName) || p.FirstName.StartsWith(FName) &&
                     p.LastName.Contains(LName) || p.LastName.StartsWith(LName))
                    select new SearchAndMergeViewModel
                    {
                        FirstName = p.FirstName,
                        LastName = p.LastName,
                        DOB = p.DOB,
                        PersonID = p.PersonID
                    };

        var queryb = from a in _Elig_DB.PersonAlias.ToList()
                     join e in _Elig_DB.PersonAttributes.ToList() on a.PersonID equals e.PersonID
                     where a.FirstName == FName && a.LastName == LName
                     select new SearchAndMergeViewModel
                     {
                         FirstName = a.FirstName,
                         LastName = a.LastName,
                         DOB = e.DOB,
                         PersonID = a.PersonID
                     };

        var results = query.Union(queryb).ToList();

        return results;
    }
```